# Android application access SQLite DB

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i hope to find a solution ASAP

i develop an android application access some data from sqlite database and the application run on the emulator perfectly but when i use its apk file in a real android device it crash and unfortunately stop message appears

I think the error because he did not find the database so how can i put my database in the right place in the device
Note that 
  * DB already in the assets folder
  * Emulator run it perfectly without put database in any specific directory

Comment: what is the crash message/log you get ?

Comment: unfortunately application has been stoped